# How to build package for ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, deb, software-sources, programming

I am starting to build a package for ubuntu. It will be a program running all the time. Just like nginx or mysqld runs.

How do I get started? Is there a framework I could use?

Suggestions pls

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question.

Comment: This is still far too broad but for a different reason. Your previous request included two separate questions, one about Debian packaging and one about SUSE packaging. Please restrict your posts to *one question* or series of closely related question. You current request is about Ubuntu packaging and about which programming language to chose, which are mostly unrelated and the latter is likely based on personal opinion rather than facts and citable references.

Comment: Ok. Updated the question again.

Comment: Thanks. That's much better.  Could you please narrow it down to what kind of *thing* you want to package? The details depend on whether it's a binary application compiled from source, a binary library compiled from source, a (collection of) scripted executable files that don't need compilation, or something entirely different (e. g. a wallpaper, a desktop theme, a manual…).

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)